# How to provide grep a file with ip addresses to look for in access.log

Tags: files, grep, logs, recursive

#### Situation

I have a file where each line has an IP address and I want to see if these Ip's are found in `access.log`

#### File name: IpAddressess

Contents example :

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.1.5
etc etc
```

Now I want to scan access.log for these IP addresses contained in the file IpAddressess

Can I use the command `grep` for this and what would the command structure look like?

Thank you kindly for any assistance!

Comment: Thank you, Steve! Very helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `-f` option, described in `man grep` on my Arch Linux system as:

```
   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.   If  this  option  is
          used  multiple  times  or  is  combined  with the -e (--regexp)
          option, search for all patterns given.  The empty file contains
          zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

However, since `grep` works with regular expressions and `.` in regular expressions means "any character", you will also want the `-F` option, so that `1.2.3` doesn't match things like `10293`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
```

Putting the two together, the command you're looking for is:

```
grep -Ff IpAddressess access.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `grep -f`.  Worth adding the `-F` to that the `.` character in your patterns doesn't get interpreted as 'any' character.

`-f` and `-F` is explained below

```
$ grep --help 2>&1|grep -i '^  \-f'
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERNS are strings
  -f, --file=FILE           take PATTERNS from FILE
$
```

Example:

```
$ cat patterns
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.1.5
$ cat myaccesslog
hello 192.168.0.1
world ! 192.168.0.2
foobar 192.168.0x1
$ grep -f patterns myaccesslog
hello 192.168.0.1
world ! 192.168.0.2
foobar 192.168.0x1
$ grep -Ff patterns myaccesslog
hello 192.168.0.1
world ! 192.168.0.2
$
```